# Show fields from MySQL differently for different users with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am creating a front-end html table using Javascript and PHP, which is going to show different results for different users from database.

```
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| Student         | Subject | Mark  |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| John Smith      | Math    | 9     |
| Mike William    | Math    | 8     |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
```

The front-end table should display results based on a users permission. If a registered user sign-in, he would see all the results, actually all fields of the table. If a non-registered user sign-in, instead of marks he would see N/A.

TABLE

a) Registered users:John Smith | Math | 9 | Mike Williams | OOP | 9

b) Visitor (Non-Registered user):John Smith | Math | N/A | Mike Williams | OOP | N/A

Do I go into the right direction?

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?> 

or

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {... } ?>
```

Then with the echo function display the tables and display the "N/A" string in the "else" part.

Or there is a smoother solution?

Comment: Personally I'd build a role based access system and determine what the user can (or can't) see at the database layer; the application can then blindly just take the results from the database queries and throw them onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Using `isset()` works for me.  With that you could put those two situation in your `if else` statement and easily execute it.
eg.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

 echo '
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| Student         | Subject | Mark  |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| John Smith      | Math    | 9     |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| Mike William    | Math    | 8     |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
';//dont forget to create your table in code
}
else{
 echo '
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| Student         | Subject | Mark  |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| John Smith      | Math    | N/A   |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
| Mike William    | Math    | N/A   |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
';
}
```